# OK button missing from javascript Prompt() in 6.5.3 ONLY

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a basic javascript Prompt that asks users to enter a number of labels for printing.  This has been working fine in Windows Mobile 6.5, but we recently upgraded to 6.5.3 and now the OK button is missing from the prompt window.  All we can do now is cancel out of the prompt.  We've tested this on 2 different devices, so I don't think it's a problem with the hardware.  Has anyone else had this problem or know of anything else I can try?

Here is the code:

```
var n = 0;
n = prompt("Number of labels to print?", "3");
```

As an extra test, I tried using the JS prompt example from w3schools.com and I get the same results.  The OK button is missing.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Here is a screenshot from the w3schools test:

[image: screenshot w3schools test]

Comment: I don't have a Mobile 6.5.3 device to test on, but I'd suggest removing the default value (3) until you get it resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried removing the default value and got the same results.  I also tried removing the prompt text, no luck. :(

Comment: Have you played around with it to see if one of those buttons could be the OK button? That is, you enter "Harry Potter" and read that value back after clicking the 'X' button.

Comment: I've tried that too. The X button minimizes the IE window.  When I re-open IE, the prompt is still open.  I've also tried hitting the Enter key hoping that would submit the response.  That didn't work either.

Comment: It looks like you may have found a bug, which sucks because `6.5.3` is the last version of Windows Mobile that Microsoft put out before switching to Windows 7 Phone.

Answer (score 0):

The w3schools prompt code works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;

var person=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");

if (person!=null)
  {
  x="Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See these three screen shots taken off a real WEH 6.5.3 device:

[image: first prompt page] [image: prompt screen] [image: result page]

**I assume you have a registry set**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shell\BubbleTiles]
"HardwareDoneKeyEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

**which hides the Software OK/Done button!**